# Load a class with all it's components from outter jar

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have this code:

```
    // Getting the jar URL which contains target class
    URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("LINKTOJAR")};

    // Create a new URLClassLoader 
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);

    // Load the target class
    Class<?> beanClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.my.class");

    // Create a new instance from the loaded class
    Constructor<?> constructor = beanClass.getConstructor();
    Object beanObj = constructor.newInstance();

    // Getting a method from the loaded class and invoke it
    Method method = beanClass.getMethod("sayHello");
    method.invoke(beanObj);
```

It's supposed to call a sayHello method that needs one bean to work.

The method prints "Hello %Name", where the name is an @AutoWired String.

The call to the method is working, but the problem is that it's just saying "Hello" because the String is not being autowired, and it's "null".

How can I make this Autowired possible, if all the context is in the jar I'm calling and seems to not being load??

Thanks.

EDIT::

The idea is to have something like:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "classpath*:**/applicationContext*.xml");

MyAdder myAdder = (MyAdder) context.getBean("myAdder");
```

In order to load the context, but I don't know how to load this context from an outter jar.

Answer (score 0):

How would you expect it to work, as Spring has no idea about your external classes - it is out of application context. Injecting indeed looks like "magic" but it is simply done by the Spring container.

You would have to use your own application context, and get bean "the Spring way".

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

One way around would be for you to inject required string to your current context, and pass it as argument to method.

Another, more "inject style" method, would be to set string by yourself using reflection - this is more or less how it is done by the Spring container internally.

Comment: Yes, that's the question, how can I load the context of the outtern jar, in order to make that work. The problem is that is not just inject the String, imagine that the String comes from a database which is configured with MyBatis... I need that logic to be load, but I can't see the way to execute de jar to have all working

Comment: You could try autowire with existing application context. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html